# Item description keyword extraction

Tags: nlp, recommendation-engine, stemming, pos-tagger

I'm playing around with a recommendation system that takes key descriptive words and phrases and matches them against others. Specifically, I'm focusing on flavors in beer, with an algorithm searching for things like `malty` or `medium bitterness`, pulling those out, and then comparing against other beers to come up with flavor recommendations.

Currently, I'm struggling with the extraction. What are some techniques for identifying words and standardizing them for later processing?

How do I pull out `hoppy` and `hops` and treat them as the same word, but also keeping in mind that `very hoppy` and `not enough hops` have different meanings that are modified by the preceding word(s)? I believe I can use stemming for things like plurals and suffixed/prefixed words, but what about pairs or more complicated patterns? What techniques exist for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would first ignore the finer-grained distinctions and compile a list of lexico-semantic patterns, which can be used to extract some information structure-- for example:

- `<foodstuff>` *has a* `<taste-description>` *taste*
- `<foodstuff>` *tastes* `<taste-description>`
- *very* `<taste-description>`
- *not enough* `<taste-description>`

You can use instances of such patterns in your text to infer useful concepts (such as different taste descriptions) which can then be used again in order to bootstrap the [extraction of new patterns and thus new concepts](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/0506/InfoRtrv/lec6.pdf).

Comment: @AFL: Can you please accept this answer if it helped you?-- I'm currently dredging for some extra reputation points. Thanks a lot.